# How Celery executes tasks

Tags: django, celery

In my project I have a Celery task that is sent by the Celery beat to the worker every 30 seconds.I am interested in knowing how celery executes the celery tasks? Whether it spawns a new thread for each task or a new worker for the task.How can we know if a task completes and is removed from the message broker queue for which I am using RabbitMQ.

Comment: It has a number of idle workers waiting for tasks to arrive so it doesn't need to spawn a new worker/thread for each incoming task.

Comment: thanks...can we control this behavior by creating new threads for tasks.

Comment: Each celery worker has its own process and each worker does only one task at a time so no threads are needed. At least I can not imagine how and why.

Comment: Oh, I may be wrong. Please refer to this part of the Celery documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Celery workers keep polling the celery queue for tasks to execute. Number of workers and number of processes(concurrency) for each worker can be configured in celery configuration file. 
Celerybeat scheduler scans through the celerybeat db and adds the tasks to the queue which are due to be executed. Then any of the free workers pick up the task from queue and executes the task and marks it as read

```
       Celery (*Manages number of workers)
Worker1      Worker2 (Reads task from celery queue and creates process for execution)
W1-P1 W1-P2    W2-P1 W2-P2 (executes the task)

Celerybeat (polls for tasks, adds due tasks to celery-queue)
```

calery-queue (contains the tasks due)

Comment: how can we configure the number of workers and number of processes in celery

Comment: You can go through this docukmentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#generic-systemd-celery-example